# error in dialog.dart and variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code

```
../../flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart(1315,48): error G44692867: A value of type 'Type' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
dialog.dart:1
../../flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart(1315,66): error G44692867: A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
dialog.dart:1

../../flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart(1316,34): error G44692867: A value of type 'Future<T?> Function<T>({Offset? anchorPoint, Color? barrierColor, bool barrierDismissible, String? barrierLabel, Widget Function(BuildContext) builder, BuildContext context, RouteSettings? routeSettings, TraversalEdgeBehavior? traversalEdgeBehavior, bool useRootNavigator, bool useSafeArea})' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
dialog.dart:1
../../flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart(1316,54): error G44692867: A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
dialog.dart:1
../../flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart(1316,111): error G44692867: A value of type 'Type' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
dialog.dart:1
../../flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart(1316,221): error G44692867: A value of type 'Element' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
dialog.dart:1
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\CMakeFiles\aec54d73671f865ab5e20342519debf8\flutter_windows.dll.rule;G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\CMakeFiles\f1c6cf0553698a1179db6516411fd53d\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1. [G:\FCI\flutter\aa\aa\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

i tried to make sure of flutter sdk and dart sdk but Without avail

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.